# How can I have two different table view cells, always in a pair, displayed in the same tableview?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I would like to put two different `tableViewCells` in the same `tableView`, so that they always appear in a pair. The first `tableViewCell` should display a start and end-time that are adjustable by the user. (maybe a `datePicker`) The second `tableViewCell` should display a `textField` that is editable as well. Both `tableViewCells` should have a little button that can either be checked or not. I would like to store that Data (Times, Text, Button status) somewhere.

I set up a struct as the `dataType` for both cells and created an array. I also set up the `cellForRowAt` but get an error there when I run the App.

To create a data type:

```
struct ScheduleCell{

    var id: Int
    var buttonState: Bool
    var text: String
    var time01: String
    var time02: String

}
```

Place to store the data:

```
var scheduleCellEntries: [ScheduleCell]! = [ScheduleCell(id: 2, buttonState: false, text: "Test", time01: "12:30", time02: "12:20"), ScheduleCell(id: 2, buttonState: false, text: "Test", time01: "12:30", time02: "12:20"), ScheduleCell(id: 2, buttonState: false, text: "Test", time01: "12:30", time02: "12:20"), ScheduleCell(id: 2, buttonState: false, text: "Test", time01: "12:30", time02: "12:20")]
```

Assigning the number of rows:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        var count: Int?

        if tableView == scheduleTableView{
            count = scheduleCellEntries.count * 2

        }
    return count!
}
```

Fetching the Data into the cells:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if tableView == scheduleTableView {

            if indexPath.row % 2 != 0{
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "scheduleCell", for: indexPath) as! scheduleTableViewCell
                cell.scheduleTextField.text = scheduleCellEntries[indexPath.row].text


        return cell
}else{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "scheduleDateCell", for: indexPath) as! ScheduleDateTableViewCell


        return cell
}
```

When I run the app I get the following error `Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range`!

Comment: You are correct to return `count * 2` as the number of rows, but you need to divide the `row` by 2 when you are accessing your array, otherwise you are trying to access an index that doesn't exist.  Personally I would create a single cell that had all of the required UI elements rather than trying to have two cells.

Comment: create a ScheduleCell with the data you need to display. because numberOfRowsInSection cannot guess what you are trying to do. And you will display it if it matches some reference value and then you can change the tableviewcell cast

Comment: Why it is important to split the data into 2 cells? If these pairs of cells *always* go together I suggest creating a single cell with all the elements necessary. In this case you will have numberOfRowsInSection = scheduleCellEntries.count

Answer (score 0):

The thing is you have X number of records in `scheduleCellEntries` but twice the number of cells in your table since you return `scheduleCellEntries.count * 2`. In `cellForRowAt` instead of using `indexPath.row` for accessing your data in `scheduleCellEntries` you should use `indexPath.row / 2`, so when the table asks for data for row 0 and 1 the same data is selected.

I change a little your sample code, I add a variable with the appropriate index to get your data `let indexOnData = indexPath.row / 2` and use it on `scheduleCellEntries`.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if tableView == scheduleTableView {
        let indexOnData = indexPath.row / 2
        if indexPath.row % 2 != 0 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "scheduleCell", for: indexPath) as! scheduleTableViewCell
            cell.scheduleTextField.text = scheduleCellEntries[indexOnData].text
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "scheduleDateCell", for: indexPath) as! ScheduleDateTableViewCell

        }
        return cell
    }
}
```